# Is saying 'What did you think' acceptable?

Tags: questions

Can you please tell me what is correct:

The situation is that you have been to a movie with another person.  At the end of the movie you ask:

> What did you think of the movie?

I want to know that persons thoughts of the movie and even though an opinion is used in the present, the movie finished and I want to know what they thought.  Is it correct to use this form?

Comment: That's the way I'd say it. *What do you think of the movie* would work too, but thoughts tend to be residual, so *what I thought* is often *what I think* still.

Comment: 'What did you think of' is the normal choice where something is definitely and completely over, even if only minutes ago. With episodes (eg you've just watched the 14th episode of _Gotham_), you can choose to focus on the episode or the ongoing series.

Comment: That's exactly what I thought!  I have a student who refuses to accept my explanation so thought I might seek some advice.  Very much appreciated!  Thanks

Comment: "What did you think of the movie?" is fine for making conversation after, though "So, whad'ja think of the movie?" would be closer to normal.  Or "Howd'ja like the movie?"  "What *do* you think of the movie?", on the other hand, seems (if asked after the movie has ended) to be asking for a technical analysis, which is usually not the intent.

Answer (score -1):

To expand a bit on what @Edwin Ashworth stated, to ask someone's thoughts *now* on something ongoing (or going on now) or will occur in the future, one uses the present tense of the verb, e.g. "What **do** you think...":

> What *do* you think of this dinner?
>   What *do* you think of the show, *Gotham*?
>   What *do* you think of Camus' philosophy?
>   How *do* you think he's going to react?
>   When do you think she will return

To ask about something that is completed/finished, use the past tense *did*:

> What *did* you think of the dinner (we just *ate*)?
>   What *did* you think of *Gotham* (that you *watched*) last night?
>   What *did* you think of Camus' *L'Étranger* (that you *read*)?
>   How *did* you think he *was going* to react?
>   When *did* you think she *was going to/would* return

Answer (score -2):

It would be better to say - "***What do you think of the movie?***.

Suppose you are driving back home after watching the movie, and you ask the same question (you want to know if your friend liked the movie or not) - ***What do you think of the movie? Will it do well overseas?*** As you are asking your friend to think at that moment so you should say - *'what **do** you think'*.

But if you want to refer to that period of time when you were watching the movie, you would say e.g. ***"what did you eat during the interval?"***

Again you can ask your friend - *"What **will** you say about the climax of the movie?"*

So it is not about the ***time*** the movie ends or is going on, its about the the ***time*** you are asking your friend to think of the movie.

Comment: "What did you think of the movie?" is perfectly fine.  You're making conversation, not analyzing it for Rotten Tomatoes.